# Called method was not the one expected

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Last week, I spent a lot (too much) of hours on a strange problem. I wanted to use `gnieh.diffson` to patch an existing object, the client send a `PATCH /api/test/patch` request with a well formed Json patch. Then I parse the patch and apply it :

```
import gnieh.diffson._ 
val patch = JsonPatch.parse(request.body.asText.getOrElse("")) 
val workspace = """{"node":{}}""" 
val result = patch(workspace) 
println(result)
```

This code works fine inside a simple `App` but fails on a play `Controller` :

> [error]    PatchException: : element node does not exist in
>   "{\"node\":{}}"  (JsonPatch.scala:140)
>   [error] gnieh.diffson.Operation.action(JsonPatch.scala:140)
>   [error] gnieh.diffson.Add.action(JsonPatch.scala:174)  ...

### The solution was to qualify everything.

The `gnieh.diffson.JsonPatch#apply` class has 3 `apply` methods :

```
def apply(json : scala.Predef.String, compacted : scala.Boolean = { /* compiled code */ }) : scala.Predef.String = { /* compiled code */ } 
def apply(value : net.liftweb.json.JValue) : net.liftweb.json.JValue = { /* compiled code */ } 
def apply[T](<value : T>)(implicit evidence\$1 : scala.Predef.Manifest[T]) : T = { /* compiled code */ }
```

I was thinking that the first one was called because "*workspace*" is a *String* but I was wrong. The called method was the last one, with implicit evidence..

My current solution is to parse the workspace as a `net.liftweb.json.JValue` but I am not verry happy with it because :
 - I can't understant why it is the last method who is called.
 - I have to format the `net.liftweb.json.JValue` to string to recreate a `play.api.libs.json.JsObject` .. (because I need it later in my process)

Could you please explain me why the called method is the more complex one ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There's a clause in the contract that discards alternatives that use default args:

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution